# Split chat log file at date (with regex) and count number of messages per month

Tags: python

I have several chat history logs and would like to count the number of messages sent and received per month. Some messages correspond to one line in the text file, but not all of them. Therefore, I want to split the messages at the date and time. Then I want to extract the month and year from each date, and count the number of messages and adjust this number in a dictionary. Finally, I want to print the month/year and the number of messages.

This is how the source file looks like (dates are `d/m/Y`):

```
09/10/2017, 10:55 - Name omitted: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
09/10/2017, 11:17 - Name omitted: Pellentesque massa tellus, porttitor et iaculis vitae, sodales ac mauris.
Aliquam ullamcorper dictum laoreet. Proin ornare ultrices eros, ut fermentum ex accumsan at. Curabitur dignissim massa a nisi molestie, id hendrerit elit convallis. 

Etiam tincidunt gravida arcu, vel lacinia tellus dignissim eu. Praesent ullamcorper neque eu tellus interdum, in semper nibh sagittis. Fusce dignissim sollicitudin mauris in tempus. Sed in magna ante.
09/10/2017, 11:29 - Name omitted: Nam eu risus laoreet, commodo neque eget, tincidunt risus. Suspendisse eu ullamcorper metus.
```

And this is my code, which unfortunately is not working. I get a long list of 1 as a result:

```
import os
import re

nummessages = {}

datafiles = ("file1.txt", "file2.txt")

for file in datafiles:
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf8") as infile:
        for line in infile: 
            regexdate = re.compile("([0-9]{2})(\/)([0-9]{2})(\/)([0-9]{4})(,)(\s)([0-9]{2})(:)([0-9]{2})")
            messages = regexdate.split(line)
            for message in messages:
                key = re.search("([0-9]{2})(\/)([0-9]{4})", message)
                value = message.count(message)

                if key in nummessages.keys():
                    nummessages[key].append(value)
                else: 
                    nummessages[key] = [value]


for key in sorted(nummessages.items()):
    print(str(key[0]) + "\t"  + str(key[1]))
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
09/2017: 45 messages
10/2017: 10 messages
...
```

What am I doing wrong? (FYI, I am new to Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

the main idea in this solution is to parse the month and year of the logs and use it as a key in `data` dictionary. Now, for every logs that matches the same month and year, an increment of 1 will be added to the dictionary's value

```
data = {} # outside

for file in datafiles:
  with open(file, "r", encoding="utf8") as infile:
    for l in infile: 
      m = re.match(r'\d{2}/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', l)
      if m:
        key = '{}/{}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2))
        if key not in data.keys():
          data[key] = 0
        data[key] += 1

# printing
for k in data:
  print '{}: {} messages'.format(k, data[k])
```

`lines` refer to each line in your log files

[image]

Comment: How does this deal with messages that run over more than one line in the file?

Comment: this code assumes that its input is already a single line that is extracted from the files you opened. In your sample code just put this inside the loops and then it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, the script seems to work with 2 corrections: There is an `else` missing before `data[key] += 1`, and the brackets around `print()` are missing the final line!

Comment: that's great then! I'll update my answer to make up your comments. :) I assume you are using python 3? I'm compiling via python 2.7. btw, the missing `else` is intended. :)

Comment: For me the script does not work without the else, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
with open(file, "r", encoding="utf8") as infile:
    for line in infile:                              #Iterate Each line
        line = line.strip()
        m = re.match("(\d{2}/(\d{2})/(\d{4}))", line)   #Check if line starts with date
        if m:
            result["{}/{}".format(m.group(2), m.group(3))] += 1   #form month/year and get count. 
print(result)
```